# Redirect all ASP to a single PHP page in Magento with .htaccess

Tags: php, redirect, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect all the requests to .aspx pages in my Magento installation to a single PHP page that will handle a redirect.

My goal is to **redirect every request of a .aspx page to migration-redirect.php** and passing the original url/aspx page to the PHP page.

**I am using the below code in the .htaccess** file in the Magento 1.8 root dir to achieve this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aspx$ /migration-redirect.php?ref=$1.aspx [NC,QSA]
```

pasted right above the `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]` code.

I have tried to paste the above code in different places of the standard Magento .htaccess file but it does not work. Each time i request for an .aspx page i get redirected to the 404 error page of Magento. I had already tried the above code on another server (without Magento) and it worked.

What am i missing? Thanks

Comment: This is not Magento related, you should ask this in a more generic SE.

Comment: Did you try with `R` flag: `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aspx$ /migration-redirect.php?ref=$1.aspx [NC,QSA,R]`

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
I have tried with the above with no luck.
The only way to make it work is to comment out the `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]` but i don't consider that as a solution...
Any other hint?

Comment: Myabe i just managed to solve the problem.
I pasted this rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aspx$ /migration-redirect.php?ref=$1.aspx [NC,QSA,L]` just below `RewriteEngine on` and it worked.
I was missing the L flag on the `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your old website page is www.baseurl.com/icatalog/p.aspx and you want to redirect it to a new plain URL below will work like charm:

```
RewriteRule ^icatalog/p\.aspx$ http://catalog.mcfeelys.com/s00178.htm [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Kind note I have placed this for those who want have static PHP redirect from aspx page of older/unwanted website.